# Content in hidden div flashes when shown

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, slider

I am building an extremely custom wordpress theme and am simply stumped by one final problem. On the featured posts slider when you click on the middle image (image pagination) the content loads then the bottom half of the image and text flashes! This only happens once, afterwards you can click back and forth between all the featured posts and there is no problem, it crossfades just fine.

I thought this must be related to some preloading issue, however all the content is shown for a split second and then its almost as if its reloaded.

http://www.charliegrove.com/barna is where I am making the theme and testing everything.

Any help diagnosing the problem would be gratefully appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please show relevant code. Preferably in an isolated test case. I don't want to waste time by working through your full site.

Comment: i tried to make a jsfiddle but its so intertwined i cant seem to get it to work there without wordpress backend but i will keep trying... do you have any hunches?

Comment: maybe just post the relevant jQuery code then... and no, no hunches.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JCyru/ here is a fiddle, i am trying to clean it up more for everyone

Comment: although, did you realise you're including two copies of jQuery?

Comment: I don't see the flashing thing with chrome 22... what browser are you testing with?

Comment: {"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: oddly enough after trying everything i could possibly think of, i changed the image and now there is no problem!! doesnt make any sense and i hope it doesnt happen again

Comment: nevermind guys... its back, i am about to throw in the towel but the client insists on having it fixed.... i would pay someone to help

Comment: Ok I have found that if i dont use crossfade then it works fine, but it is imperative that i use the crossfade function